# Django - User Password Change by coding

Tags: django, django-users

I am trying to give permission to change password for logged in user. coded as below.. result comes as password has been changed but password not set.

Note: template having three text box

1. "old" for current password
2. "password" for new password
3. "confirm" for confirmation of new password.

```py
def changepassword(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = authenticate(request, username=request.user,password=request.POST['old'])
        if user is None:
            return render(request, 'pmp/changepassword.html', {'error': 'Current Password Enter Mismatch! '})
        else:
            try:
                if request.POST['password'] == request.POST['confirm']:
                    u = request.user
                    u.set_password('password')
                    return render(request, 'pmp/changepassword.html', {'success':'Password has been changed!'})
                else:
                    return render(request, 'pmp/changepassword.html',{'form': AuthenticationForm(), 'error': 'New Password and confirm Password mismatch!'})    
            except ValueError:
                return render(request, 'pmp/changepassword.html',{'form': AuthenticationForm(), 'error': 'Password not changed!'})
            
    return render(request, 'pmp/changepassword.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `save()` on the user after setting the password, `set_password()` does not save the new password to the DB

```py
    u = request.user
    u.set_password(request.POST['password'])
    u.save() # Add this line
```

Comment: Thanks! its working now.. I have doubt. if user is trying to set weak password, will it accept it while change password?

Comment: `set_password` will not check the strength of the password - there is a built-in function you can call to check the passwords strength https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.password_validation.validate_password